# Create a annotation on a class to verify two dates with Kotlin/Java

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I want to verity two dates parameters in a class, start day must before end day. However, I have multiple classes which have this demand, so I want to customize a generic annotation.

what I have tried:

`class dataValidator<T : Any>: ConstraintValidator<DateConstraint, T>`

It raised a error:

`javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'my.test.annotation.DateValid' validating type 'my.test.model.DateModel'. Check configuration for ''`

However, if I change my validator to this, and it works
`class dataValidator<T : Any>: ConstraintValidator<DateConstraint, DateModel>`

So, is there any way I can write a generic annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this problem will happen when you are trying to use incorrect validator annotation on any bean property, you must use the right annotations for the right types.

You can find more information [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/unexpectedtypeexception-error/)